# How to change the menu icon 2021

Tags: pi-3b+

i have a Raspberry Pi 3 model B+ I have installed Raspbian OS on it.

So i have looked it up but all i can find is outdated guides. i have tried to replace the launch image in /usr/share/raspberry-artwork but that didn't work

thanks

Comment: launch image .... menu icon ... they don't sound like the same thing .... what is it you're trying to change?

Comment: i followed a tutorial on how to change the menu icon and thats how they did it but it didnt work for me

Comment: so, what is a "launch image"?

Comment: idk and sry for tha late reply

Comment: you don't know what a "launch image" is ... but you want to change it ...

Comment: no that was the guide that i was but it didnt work all im trying to is to change the menu icon on the rpi in any way possible